# sklearn metrics units of Measurement of accuracy, mean absolut error, mean squared error for regression problems?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, metrics, confusion-matrix

Which unit of measurement has the accuracy, mean absolut error and mean squared error of the sklearn metrics? and are they used for regression problems? 
For example i have a regressor.score(X_test,y_test)) of about 0.99469. So the tested Model is 0.99469 in comparison to the real data? or do you say percent of 99%? 
The same with the MAE and MSE.

The other question is, i red about the confusion matrix for classification problems and the accuracy is the value calculated out of the confusion matrix. I use a multiple linear regression, so can i use these metrics for my regression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, the metric such as **accuracy can't be used for regression problems**. And yes, you are right. The accuracy is calculated using the confusion matrix, but since you have a regression problem, you can't get the confusion matrix as it is an output of the classification problem but you have a regression problem in place.

Moreover, the right metrics for the regression problem are mean squared error, mean absolute error and the R squared value. By default the ***regressor.score(X_test,y_test))*** function gives out the R squared value.

To make it easy, the closer the value is to 1 (0.99469 in your case), the better is your model. And it seems like your model is performing really well.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, `metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred)` and `metrics.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)` will give you those respective metrics.

`regressor.score(X_test, y_test)` is effectively `metrics.r2_score` which is the R^2 value, i.e. can be interpreted as the amount of variance explained by the model. In your case, you'd say that 99.469% of the variation in the data is explained by your model (for the training data).

Check: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#regression-metrics

and http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html

Traditionally, confusion matrices are not used for regression problems, but there are other ways to evaluate your mlr model, all (for `sklearn`) are linked above